# How to use my firebase authentication to work with external services?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Ok so I am using firebase as authentication for my iOS app. Now I plan on adding video calling to my app using an external service know as connectyCube. This service has their own authentication system and I cannot use their services unless a user is authenticated.

- Option 1: I can use their own authentication which means my app would have two authentication systems - not very productive
- Option 2: They say I can use an existing authentication to validate users

I understand that this is a common thing in the developers world and I see the word OAuth and JWT being thrown around but I am a rookie developer and I want to understand how I can use firebase and authenticate a user from an external service.

These are the questions they have asked when I opted for the "I have my own authentication" option:

1. What is your end point URL
2. Is it GET or POST
3. Request Headers
4. Request Params
5. Response Params

Where do I get all this information from firebase? Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to [@Dharmaraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13130697) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68164127/3068190), you could instead make use of a [HTTP Event Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) for this based on the [code sample they've provided](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/custom-idp-starter-kit/blob/main/app.js).

Using this method, you create the endpoint `/verifyUserToken` to be used by ConnectyCube.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const verifyUserToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.query.token;

  verifyUser(idToken)
    .then(
      (userData) => {
        res.status(200).json(userData)
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("Token verification failed.", err.code || err.message);
        res.status(422).json({error: "User token is invalid"})
      }
    )
    .catch((err) => console.error("Unexpected crash", err));
});

async function verifyUser(token) {

  if (!token)
    throw new Error("token missing");

  // using `true` here to force token to be checked against the Firebase
  // Auth API rather than trusting its contents as-is
  const { uid, email } = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token, true);

  // pull the user's username from their user data
  // at /users/{userId}/username
  const username = (await admin.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/username")).val();

  // use user's actual email if available, otherwise fallback
  // to a userID based email
  const uEmail = email || uid + "@users.noreply.yourapp.com";

  // use user's username if available, otherwise fallback to
  // the email address above.
  const uLogin = username !== null ? username : uEmail; 

  return {
    uid,
    login: uLogin,
    email: uEmail,
    user: {id: uid, login: uLogin, email: uEmail}, // <- this part in particular is used by ConnectyCube
    users: [{uid, login: uLogin, email: uEmail}]
  };
}
```

Once deployed, you would use the following settings:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| API URL: | `https://us-central1-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/verifyUserToken` |
| GET/POST | `GET` |
| Request params: | `{"token": "#{login}"}` |
| Response params: | `{"uid": "#{user.id}", "email": #{user.email}, "login": "#{user.login}"}` |

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I will try implementing this as well as what @dharmaraj recommended and see how it goes. Will update on pros and cons

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ConnectyCube uses some sort of Session Tokens as mentioned in their [documentation](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/authentication-and-users) with their own username and password.

The most easiest way would be creating a ConnectyCube account whenever a new user signs up in your Firebase app using [Firebase Auth Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) for Cloud functions. Then you can generate username and password on behalf of your user and store them in a Database.

So whenever you need to create a ConnectyCube session, check for the currently logged in user and fetch their ConnectyCube credentials.

```
async function createCCSession() {
  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  const ccCrednetials = (await firebase.database().ref(`ccCreds/${userId}`).once('value')).val()
  
  ConnectyCube.createSession(ccCredentials)
    .then((session) => {
      console.log(session)
      return session
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

You can protect the database using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) so a user can access their credentials only.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "ccCreds": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did think about using Auth triggers. I'll probably execute it and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort ... :)

Comment: I would love to accept your answer and I have given it an upvote. But I am accepting @samthecodingman 's solution because I am more interested in understanding how authentication using external services ties up with existing authentication systems. I have always found JWT and oAuth confusing lol

Comment: @Archid . At the end it kind of comes down to whether you really need to use a Cloud function to get a user's credential each time or an auth trigger once will suffice with the database costs. You could use [Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which would authenticate the Firebase user for you..

Comment: Oh yes that is true ... firebase costs are very high for users to be authenticated via database calls again and again

Comment: @Archid although I meant using (database + functions) adds more cost than using only (database).

Comment: I think I will end up using your proposed solution for production because of what you said. It makes sense to do that and it is much more simple to execute.

Comment: @Archid glad to hear that. You could even store some info (not passwords) in custom claims if they are handy .

Answer (score 0):

While I don't normally double-answer a question, in the course of exploring some other authentication related problems, I've managed to eliminate the Cloud Function from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167617/3068190) entirely and instead call the Authentication API directly.

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| API URL: | `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=FIREBASE_CONFIG_API_KEY` |
| GET/POST | `POST` |
| Request params: | `{"idToken": "#{login}"}` |
| Response params: | `{"uid": "#{users.0.localId}", "email": #{users.0.email}, "full_name": "#{users.0.displayName}"}` |

On your client, you just call the ConnectyCube Login API with the following data:

```
POST https://api.connectycube.com/login
login=<Firebase-ID-token>
password=<any-random-value-to-pass-the-validation>
```